# Strange spectral types in star catalogs

Tags: star-catalogues, spectral-type

I'm collecting different star catalogs I've found in the Internet to make my own and I noticed some "strange" peculiarity in how those catalogs describe spectral type of a star.

Namely:

- sometimes the type has got a slash like "G8/K0III". Does it mean it is a binary star system? A variable star? A measurement uncertainty?
- other types has an ellipsis: "K0...". This one is a completely mystery to me...
- you can find even "+" and ":"
- and the last but not least: plain weird names like "K1IIICN..."

May someone explain where those enigmatic descriptions come from? What in the way a spectral type is determined in observatories makes the need of such things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [pretty comprehensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Spectral_peculiarities) of all these peculiarities and their meaning. Spectral classification also is not always unique or unambiguous.

- "/" denotes stars which could be classified as either
- "..." denotes undescribed peculiarities
- "+" denotes hypergiants. But see there also for deviating use of "f+" or "(f+)".
- ":" denotes uncertain spectral classification
- C,N,O, (any element symbol) denotes particularily strong lines from that element(s)

That said, any catalogue might want to explain uncommon nomenclature in its notes.